# Create screenshots when running as Windows Service

Tags: java, windows, windows-services, uac

I've created a java program which is installed as a Windows service on a win10 machine using winsw. This program needs access to the current user desktop as it periodically creates screenshots (using `java.awt.Robot`) and processes them.

Because windows services run in their own session0 that isn't possible (I get black images). So how can I create my screenshots without creating another program which is run by the user session itself?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `<interactive>` True in your configurations file in order to allow service to interact with Session 0. But in UAC OS(Windows vista or Above) services are no longer allow to interact with the Desktop.

ex :- `<interactive />`

For further information read [this.](https://github.com/winsw/winsw/blob/master/doc/xmlConfigFile.md#interactive)

Comment: That 's why I wrote I use win10. The UAC is exactly the reason why I asked this question.

Comment: Did you set <interactive> true in Configuration xml

Comment: Yes. and (as you already said) the docu says: "Note that since the introduction UAC (Windows Vista and onward), services are no longer really allowed to interact with the desktop. In those OSes, all that this does is to allow the user to switch to a separate window station to interact with the service."

Comment: Hmm.. I think I have lack of knowledge in this area. Anyway sorry for the inconvenient answer.